# Is it possible to run a local python script with a remote ssh interpreter via Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

Is it possible to run a local python script with a remote ssh interpreter via Visual Studio Code?

I have a python project on a remote Linux server machine, and I want to copy the code to my local machine and debug it via remote python interpreter with all its accesses and permissions to databases etc.

Comment: why not run it on the remote server, VSC remote is just a viewer of the VSC instance running on the remote machine

Comment: Couse my project is on GitLab with limited access, i have this acces with ssh keys etc on my local machine only.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you want to execute the remote server code on your local machine with remote server settings?

Comment: If I can comment (I gave the bounty)... yes, I would like to use VSCode for local development, syncing files with a remote server, and execute the code with remote python interpreter -- the same way as is common with PyCharm. In general, fully remote development is better, but I have some troubles that VSCode is causing the server to restart if I connect.. And it seems I'm not alone https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2692 but that's another story.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the ability to install [`rmate`](https://github.com/textmate/rmate) on the remote server, then you can use [Remote VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode).

For this, extension's documentation describes, you configure the VS Code user settings for the extension, start the extension's server from the command palette with `Remote: Start server`, open an ssh connection to the remote server with a remote port forwarded with `ssh -R 52698:localhost:52698 user@example.com`, and then you run `rmate -p 52698 <file>` on the remote server.

This will cause the specified file to open up in your local VS Code editor, and any changes made to it there will be reflected in the copy on the remote server very soon after you save them.

---

Alternatively, you can use `sshfs` to mount the remote directory as if it were a local directory. This is my preferred method nowadays for editing remote files using a local editor. On systems using apt you can install it with `apt install sshfs`. On systems using yum you can install it with `yum install fuse-sshfs`.

Once installed, make a local directory in which you'll mount the remote directory. We'll call it `/mnt/remote` for this example. Go ahead and mount it with sshfs:

```sh
sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions user@example.com:<src dir> /mnt/remote
```

Where `<src dir>` is the absolute path to the remote directory you would like local access to.

Add the `IdentityFile=/home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa` option after `default_permissions` if you are using key authorization, as you ought to be.

You may need to tweak the permissions of `/mnt/remote`, and use `sudo` for all of the commands listed above.

[Many other options are detailed in the man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs). Consider also using `large_read` for greater efficiency, and `reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=5,ServerAliveCountMax=15` for greater reliability.

Once the `sshfs` command succeeds, you should find that the remote directory is accessible as the local directory `/mnt/remote`. To edit the contents of the remote locally, simply open up VS Code to that directory with `code /mnt/remote`, and edit away as if it were all local! Your changes will be reflected in the remote files very soon after you save them.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, how does it go with using a remote interpreter? (At the end, I bought PyCharm for my imminent tasks, but this mounting stuff is helpful....)

Comment: @PeterFranek with either approach I mentioned, if you wanted local access to a remote interpreter, you would open it with an SSH terminal. To persist a terminal across multiple connections you could use `tmux`, or other similar programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a fully remote development environment using [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) extension to access you remote server. Currently this is the most convenient option. I guess you already know about this extension. I've being using it for about a year, it works fine for me. The "restart" issue is most probably connected to combination of "Amazon Linux" (based on CentOS) kernel and out-of-memory problem. Make sure you have >4Gb of memory available (on a remote machine) as VSCode "eats up" at least 1Gb. And once you are out of memory the remote machine will most probably just hang. Try to change to Ubuntu based kernel, if you still have troubles.

Another option is to run Jupyter Lab/Notebook on remote machine. This will allow you to edit, run and debug code in the local browser window. (You will have to keep some port open on remote and connect using `ssh -L` option).

Another possible solution is to use extensions like [Sync-Rsync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscode-ext.sync-rsync) or [Remote VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rafaelmaiolla.remote-vscode) to sync/edit remote code in your local VSCode instance or you can use any GUI-based SSH client to edit the remote code locally. But this way you're loosing the ability to run/debug remotely.

I will also mention that PyCharm (professional edition is required) have the ability to edit files locally, then sync and run/debug on remote.

Comment: Thanks a lof for your remarks. I wish you were right in the first paragraph... However, my remote machine is not Amazon (but is CentOs) and has right now at least 33 GB free ram... Maybe I will switch to PyCharm then

Comment: You can try Pycharm Community Edition, it has all the options of Professional one enabled for the first month. Also, I've used [web server version of VSCode](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) before Remote SSH was available. It runs VSCode on remote and provides you access to it via web browser.